# Finding out what version of webkit flexbox was added in

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit, android-browser, flexbox

I'm having problems using flexbox in android browser, even if I use all the following style rules I still get `display:block` as the computed style

```
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box; 
  display: box; 
  display: -ms-flexbox; 
  display: -webkit-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
```

The webkit build number is 535.19 (chrome 18.0.1025.308), but finding information about what's included in that release is proving very difficult (including checking webkit.org).

Where can I find out what features were added to which version of webkit?

Comment: I just worked out that `-webkit-flexbox` conflicts with `-webkit-box` in this version of android and that was my problem.

Comment: OK. By the way, [MDN's page about the display property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) doesn't mention any property value with `box` in the name.